# Lost book: ER doctor dreams of seven non-humanoid aliens who commit suicide

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

Story begins with female divorced ER doctor who has recurring dreams of seven non-humanoid aliens who commit suicide by poison.  The dreams have grown increasingly frequent and disturbing, and her health is impacted - and she questions her sanity.

She's still friendly with her gay ex-husband, who is alarmed by her physical condition, and insists she see a doctor.

And that's the point I put it down, and now, unfortunately, I can't find what I did with it, nor can I recall title or author.

Comment: Look under your bed, or behind your bedside table.

Comment: Believe me, I've looked. I can't fathom how it is that I can't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems I forgot it was only a teaser from the back of the author's most recent previous title.  No wonder I couldn't find it.

Here's the title in question:

> **Rising Darkness** (A Game of Shadows Novel) by Thea Harrison *(release date: April 2nd, 2013)*

Comment: [It's out!](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Rising-Darkness-Number-Game-Shadows/dp/0749958979/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1364909006&sr=8-1)